# Poker app in C#

Tags: c#, performance, array, collections, enum

I am developing a poker application using C#. It is almost done, and I'm looking for improvements. One of the things I wonder is whether I should change my method that checks if the player has a flush. It's quite big compared to the others but it works just fine, however, something can be improved. Maybe put some of the stuff in collections, but I am not sure if that's going to hurt the overall performance.

In the following code, I'm using the `%` operator and dividing by 4 because there are 4 cards of the same type but with different colors. The deck of cards for playing poker consists of 52 cards. I start to count them from 0. If we take the cards starting from ace up to king we will have 0-51 what we can do from here is assume that each Ace (0,1,2,3) has result when divided by 4 , 0 (`0 /4 = 0, 1 / 4 = 0`) so on.

But in the current method, I am using the `%` operator. This helps me determine what's the current color of the card because the clubs are 0-4-8-12-16. When we divide 0,4,8,12,16 by 4 (`4 % 4`) we get result 0. These are the Clubs and Diamonds: 1-5-9-13-17 and `1 % 4 = 1`. That's what we are getting from the f1,f2,f3,f4 arrays. How many cards of each color we have on the table.

```
//straight1[] contains info about the five cards on the table

    private UsersProperties RFlush(UsersProperties user, int[] straight1)
    {
        const int localType = (int)Type.Combinations.Flush;
        int[] currentColors = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
        int maxColor;
        int[] f1 = straight1.Where(o => o%4 == (int) Cards.Colors.Club).ToArray();
        int[] f2 = straight1.Where(o => o%4 == (int) Cards.Colors.Diamond).ToArray();
        int[] f3 = straight1.Where(o => o%4 == (int) Cards.Colors.Heart).ToArray();
        int[] f4 = straight1.Where(o => o%4 == (int) Cards.Colors.Spade).ToArray();

        bool[] conditions3 = {f1.Length == 3, f2.Length == 3, f3.Length == 3, f4.Length == 3};
        bool[] conditions4 = {f1.Length == 4, f2.Length == 4, f3.Length == 4, f4.Length == 4};
        bool[] conditions5 = {f1.Length == 5, f2.Length == 5, f3.Length == 5, f4.Length == 5};

        int correct3 = Array.IndexOf(conditions3, true);
        int correct4 = Array.IndexOf(conditions4, true);
        int correct5 = Array.IndexOf(conditions5, true);

        List<int[]> places = new List<int[]> {f1, f2, f3, f4};

        for (int j = 0; j < places.ToArray().Length; j++)
        {
            if (correct3 != j && correct4 != j && correct5 != j) continue;
            currentColors = places[j];
            break;
        }

        if (_reserve[_i]%4 == _reserve[_i + 1]%4)
        {
            if (_reserve[_i]/4 > _reserve[_i + 1]/4)
            {
                maxColor = _reserve[_i + 1]/4 == (int) Cards.Numbers.Ace ? 13 : _reserve[_i];
            }
            else
            {
                maxColor = _reserve[_i + 1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_reserve[_i]%4 == currentColors[0]%4)
            {
                maxColor = _reserve[_i];
            }
            else if (_reserve[_i + 1]%4 == currentColors[0]%4)
            {
                maxColor = _reserve[_i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                maxColor = -1;
            }
        }
        if (maxColor == -1) return user;
        if (currentColors.Length == 3)
        {
            if (_reserve[_i]%4 == _reserve[_i + 1]%4 && _reserve[_i]%4 == currentColors[0]%4)
            {
                int abc;
                if (_reserve[_i]/4 > _reserve[_i + 1]/4)
                {
                    abc = _reserve[_i]/4;
                }
                else
                {
                    abc = _reserve[_i + 1]/4;
                }
                UpdateHand(user, localType, abc);
            }
        }
        if (currentColors.Length == 4)
        {
            if (maxColor%4 == currentColors[0]%4)
            {
                UpdateHand(user, localType, maxColor);
            }
        }
        if (currentColors.Length != 5 || currentColors.Max() <= 0 || maxColor%4 != currentColors[0]%4)
            return user;
        if (currentColors[0]/4 == (int) Cards.Numbers.Ace && maxColor/4 > currentColors[1]/4)
        {
            UpdateHand(user, localType, maxColor);
        }
        else if (currentColors[0]/4 < maxColor/4)
        {
            UpdateHand(user, localType, maxColor);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Here's the enum `Colors`. Can this be made into `static` variables?

```
public static class Cards
{
    public enum Colors
    {
        Club = 0,
        Diamond = 1,
        Heart = 2,
        Spade = 3
    }
}
```

Here's the `UpdateHand` method and the `User` class needed:

```
    private void UpdateHand(UsersProperties user, int combinationType, int powerType)
    {
        user.Type = combinationType;
        user.Power = powerType + user.Type * 100;
        _win.Add(new Type { Power = user.Power, Current = user.Type });
    }

public class UsersProperties
{
    public int LeftCard;
    public int RightCard;
    public string Name;
    public int? Chips;
    public int Type;
    public double Power;
    public bool Turn;
    public bool FoldTurn;
    public int PreviousCall { get; set; }
    public int EnumCasted;

    public Point CardsLocation;
    public AnchorStyles CardsAnchor;

    public readonly Panel Panel = new Panel();
    public Point PanelLocation;
    public Size PanelSize = new Size((Settings.Width + 10) * 2, Settings.Height + 20);
    public int IndentationPanelXy = 10;

    public Label UsernameLabel = new Label();
    public Point UsernameLabelLocation;
    public Size UsernameLabelSize = new Size(Settings.Width * 2, 20);

    public TextBox ChipsTextBox = new TextBox();
    public Label StatusLabel = new Label();
}
public class Player : UsersProperties
    {
        public Player(int? chips,Point cardsLocation)
        {
            LeftCard = 1;
            RightCard = 0;
            Name = "Player";
            Chips = chips;
            Type = -1;
            Power = 0;
            Turn = true;
            FoldTurn = false;
            CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            PreviousCall = 0;
            EnumCasted = (int)CUser.Player;
            CardsLocation = cardsLocation;
            UsernameLabelLocation = new Point(CardsLocation.X, CardsLocation.Y + Settings.Height);
            PanelLocation = new Point(CardsLocation.X - IndentationPanelXy, CardsLocation.Y - IndentationPanelXy);
        }
        public Player(int? chips, bool turn, bool foldTurn, AnchorStyles style, Point cardsLocation)
        {
            LeftCard = 1;
            RightCard = 0;
            Name = "Player";
            Chips = chips;
            Type = -1;
            Power = 0;
            Turn = turn;
            FoldTurn = foldTurn;
            CardsAnchor = style;
            PreviousCall = 0;
            EnumCasted = (int)CUser.Player;
            CardsLocation = cardsLocation;
            UsernameLabelLocation = new Point(CardsLocation.X, CardsLocation.Y + Settings.Height);
            PanelLocation = new Point(CardsLocation.X - IndentationPanelXy, CardsLocation.Y - IndentationPanelXy);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implement base-4 arithmetic. Overload + and - operators, etc. That will greatly simplify things. Sorry, kidding. Re-consider basic structures - how cards, suits, card values, a deck are represented. For me the code is incomprehensible. Cards of the same suit are usually represented sequentially rather than the 4 aces represented by modulo arithmetic. You define suits clearly w/ an enum then transmutilate that into an arithmetic problem. IMHO any answer at this point is  just re-arranging the deck chairs on the Titanic until fundamental design issues are addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Encapsulation.

Your `UserProperties` class actually contains exactly **ONE** so-called property.

> ```
> public int PreviousCall { get; set; }
> ```

This member looks something like this at run-time:

```
private int _previousCall;

public int get_PreviousCall() { return _previousCall; }
public void set_PreviousCall(int value) { _previousCall = value; }
```

Everything else you have in that class is called a *field*. And public fields break *encapsulation*, one of the four pillars of Object-Oriented Programming.

---

#### Separation of Concerns.

There's another major problem with `UserProperties`. It knows about way too many things. It seems it should be concerned with *data*, not with *presentation* yet...

> ```
> public Point CardsLocation;
> public AnchorStyles CardsAnchor;
>
> public readonly Panel Panel = new Panel();
> public Point PanelLocation;
> public Size PanelSize = new Size((Settings.Width + 10) * 2, Settings.Height + 20);
> public int IndentationPanelXy = 10;
>
> public Label UsernameLabel = new Label();
> public Point UsernameLabelLocation;
> public Size UsernameLabelSize = new Size(Settings.Width * 2, 20);
>
> public TextBox ChipsTextBox = new TextBox();
> public Label StatusLabel = new Label();
> ```

`Labels` and `TextBox` controls belong in the UI, not in your data.

The `Player` class has literally no reason to not *be* the `UserProperties` class - this inheritance tree is completely artificial and superfluous. I think my first refactoring would be to move the `UserProperties` members into the `Player` class, and then get rid of `UserProperties`.

The dependency on the `UserProperties` type is a false abstraction; you're really depending on a specific implementation. This is a misuse of inheritance.

---

I need to say something about this snippet:

> ```
> int abc;
> if (_reserve[_i]/4 > _reserve[_i + 1]/4)
> {
>     abc = _reserve[_i]/4;
> }
> else
> {
>     abc = _reserve[_i + 1]/4;
> }
> UpdateHand(user, localType, abc);
> ```

What's up with the magic `4` here? If that stands for the number of suits in a deck of cards, then it should be clearer than that. Also, what's the meaning of `abc`? And what is `localType`?

> ```
> const int localType = (int)Type.Combinations.Flush;
> ```

That's utterly confusing. `Type` is a .NET class; if it's yet another static class that's just another container for the `Combinations` enum, it's wrong.

> *Here's the `enum Cards.Colors` maybe this can be made into static variables?*

There's nothing wrong with using an enum for this. Except enum types shouldn't be pluralized, so that would be `Color`, and if you're using the `Cards` class as a container for the enum, note that you can get rid of it - enums can perfectly live inside a namespace, they're full-fledged types too!

That said, I'd go with `Suit` instead of `Color`, and drop the redundant explicit numbering:

```
public enum Suit
{
    Club,
    Diamond,
    Heart,
    Spade
}
```

Similarly, the `Combinations` enum should be `Combination`, and again the semantic value of the enum member is the member itself, not its underlying `int`.

Same with `Cards.Numbers`, which would probably be better off as `FaceValue`. When I see a pluralized class name (like `Cards`), I expect there's another class (singular) with a similar name (e.g. `Card`), and that the plural one represents some kind of *collection of* the singular one, e.g. `Cards : ICollection<Card>`.

You're abusing `static` classes here.

Comment: Actually there's a bot class which also inherits from the user properties and im using those controls but i just haven't shown it here im create a lot of stuff using those variables that UserProperties contains i will also add some parts of the `Bot` Class and im sorry but i didn't understood what's the problem when i break the encapsulation ?

Comment: See on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/161308/68834), [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/480637/1188513) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=vs.71).aspx). Of course you're using these controls - what I'm saying is that they don't belong *there*. Controls belong in a UI, not in a class that's meant to hold data! Consider using, and coding against, an `interface` instead of deriving from a non-abstract class. And keep things *cohesive*, too - a well-designed interface doesn't expose 20 members.